# In angular js- how to redirect to home page , when user changed url

Tags: angularjs

In angular js , how to redirct the url .
When user changed tab1 to tab2 in url, it must be redirect to tab1.

Comment: you can try $window.location

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle it.. Few of them:

1. Manage in your Routeconfig.
2. Manage it in your controller, by changing `$location.path()`
3. Manage via `$locationChangeStart` event listener. Like below :

   `scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
     // manage navigation here.
   });`

See this attached [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nc25oc62/), try with uncommenting code as well.